# How to calculate days,hours,minutes,seconds from seconds in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns in a table.
    1.meterno
    2.duration_time (sec), 
I want to Calculate in Days, Hours, Minutes & Seconds from duration_time(sec).

Output should be in below format  when we pass only seconds.
6 Days 16 Hours 26 Min 0 Sec

```
SELECT column1,
       CASE WHEN (column2 IS NOT NULL)
                 THEN (((((((date_part('day'::text, CAST(column2 as INTEGER)) ||
                                       ' Days '::text) ||
                             date_part('hour'::text, CAST(column2 as INTEGER))) ||
                                       ' Hours '::text) ||
                             date_part('minute'::text, CAST(column2 as INTEGER))) ||
                                       ' Min '::text) ||
                             date_part('second'::text, CAST(column2 as INTEGER))) ||
                                       ' Sec '::text)
                ELSE NULL::text END AS event_duration
FROM Tablename;
```

Comment: What about `justify_interval(make_interval(secs => duration_time))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do the artithmetic:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    (column2 / (60*60*24))::text || ' Days ' ||
    ((column2 % (60*60*24)) / 3600)::text || ' Hours ' ||
    (((column2 % (60*60*24)) % 3600) / 60)::text || ' Minutes ' ||
    (column2 % 60)::text || ' Second' AS event_duration
FROM Tablename;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo